# Operation with a date vector returns this message: Error in charToDate(x)

Tags: r, date

I have a problem with some date variables in my data. I already checked other similar questions here but I couldn't find the answer.

I have a very long dataset and some date vectors. The data was originally in stata format, I've tried to change them into R date format with:

```
    as.Date(example$dstart)
```

which seems to work, after checking the class of the vector; but then I realised that apparently some cases are not in the standard unambiguous format that R requires, I realised when I was trying to convert "." into NAs, when I got this message

```
       Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

This is an example of the data that I have:

```
       head(sample)
       dstart    dstart2     dleave Ind   
   2005-03-20       <NA> 2005-11-19   1  
   2005-10-27 2006-07-07 2005-11-15   2     
   2000-02-29 2008-04-16 2005-03-02   3     
   2003-09-10 2007-07-23 2005-04-05   4     
   2004-04-24 2006-02-28 2005-10-17   5      
   2005-08-16       <NA> 2005-08-20   6
```

I presume that there are a few cases in the wrong format, but I don't know how to identify those cases.

Could you please advice me how to change the format of the of the date vector into an R format? I've tried this but it doesn't solve my problem.

```
      as.Date(example$dstart, format = "%Y/%m/%d")
```

This has caused me some problem in my analysis when trying to sort by date, some dates are sorted before when they are obviously posterior.

[A sample of the data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1fBTI2yri4QNkpLaWdVbW5ZMzA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your example data i.e. `sample` didn't have such a problem.  If there are multiple format, one option would be to use `library(lubridate);

Comment: You can upload it in dropbox and provide us the link

Comment: @ akrun, I know the problem is not evident in my example.I'll try to upload it in google drive, since I don't have dropbox. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, a reproducible example is needed.  Have you tried using the functions in lubridate

Comment: I've just uploaded a link to google drive. I'll also check the option in lubridate now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date format specification is using "/" instead of "-". If all your data is like your example, this should do it:

```
as.Date(example$dstart, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: How silly!!! I did it now, but I still get the same message when trying to identify missings. Anyway, my problem is not only about the missings, I'll check whether a got the same error than before when sorting and I let you know. 
Thanks you for your answer